# logger.log is not logging to alfresco.log

Tags: javascript, log4j, alfresco

I am trying to use logger.log("Hello") in a javascript file corresponding to a template page in Alfresco.

I have set the following:
- in custom-log4j.properties (overriding log4j.properties)

```
log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.File=alfresco.log
log4j.appender.File.Append=true
log4j.appender.File.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] %m%n

log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts=warn
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.BaseWebScriptTest=info
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.AlfrescoRhinoScriptDebugger=off
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger=debug
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.cmis.rest.CMISTest=info
```

But when I use logger.log in the js file, I get logger is not defined.

The solution was to set the following in custom-slingshot-application-context.xml

```
<bean id="webframework.rendition.processor.webtemplate" class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebTemplateProcessor">
      <property name="templateProcessorRegistry" ref="webframework.templates.registry.templateprocessor" />
      <property name="scriptProcessorRegistry"   ref="webframework.templates.registry.scriptprocessor" />
      <property name="processorModelHelper"      ref="processor.model.helper"></property>
      <property name="webFrameworkConfigElement" ref="webframework.config.element"></property>
      <property name="scriptObjects">
         <map>
            <entry key="remote" value-ref="webframework.webscripts.scriptremote" />
            <entry key="stringUtils">
               <bean class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptableUtils"/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="logger">
               <bean class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptLogger"/>
            </entry>
         </map>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

Now using logger.log does not give any error, but it seems that it's not writing to alfresco.log which is located in Tomcat/bin

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: In which context is your JS script running? alfresco or share? It seems to be a SURF/Share JS - so by default your log output will be in share.log

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you got confused with what applies to the repository and what applies to share.

**In the repository**:

`logger.log` uses the category `org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger` at level debug, so what you have in `custom-log4j.properties` is correct (the appender is ignored though). Make sure it is in the classpath at `alfresco/extension`. The directory `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension` is what you usually want.

**In share**:

`logger.log` uses the category `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptLogger`. As far as I remember, there is no "custom-log4j property configuration mechanism" available there, so you'll have to append

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.ScriptLogger=debug
```

to `share/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties`.

Comment: Ad logger category **in Share**: Actually when you look at the mentioned ScriptLogger class, it uses the same logger category as the repository:

    `// NOTE: keep compatibility with repository script logger`
    `private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog("org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger");`

(tested with Alfresco 4.2.f)

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to restart alfresco and execute your script in repository, there is another way as work-around solution. Try to use logger.system.out other than logger.log and you will still find the logging message in catalina.out.