# Modify types coming in the workflow list in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Alfresco 5.0.d and want to modify the list coming in the below screenshot.

[image: select workflow]

So far I got workflow.lib.js file which is having getWorkflowDefinitions() method for getting the workflow types but I'm not able to debug the values to understand the method.

I tried logger.log to see values but nothing came.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For enabling JavaScript debug/infor logs check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18891314/2307988) :

> logger.log uses the category `org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptLogger`
>   at level debug, so what you have in custom-log4j.properties is correct
>   (the appender is ignored though). Make sure it is in the classpath at
>   alfresco/extension. The directory 
>   `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension` is what you usually want.

---

**UPDATE:**

1. If you just want to hade few workflows, then you probably do not need to override the JS controller at all, check [this link](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/2503c4738893e6f55c8a0e5b8ae98741edf0f093/wcmquickstart-module/wcmquickstartsharemodule/src/main/amp/config/alfresco/wcmquickstart-share-config.xml#L82). It has probably what you are looking for.
2. As for debugging JS backed Webscripts, check [this](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/ws-controller-debug.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable client side debugger also in share-config or share-config-custom.xml file.

```
<flags>
     <!--
        Developer debugging setting to turn on DEBUG mode for client scripts in the browser
     -->
     <client-debug>false</client-debug>
     <!--
        LOGGING can always be toggled at runtime when in DEBUG mode (Ctrl, Ctrl, Shift, Shift).
        This flag automatically activates logging on page load.
     -->
     <client-debug-autologging>false</client-debug-autologging>

     <!--
        When this is set to true any Aikau based errors will be posted back to the server and 
        captured by the server side logging. This can be useful to detect when errors occur in 
        a users browser -->
     <post-client-debug>false</post-client-debug>
  </flags>
```

`getWorkflowDefinitions()` method returns all the workflows which are running in your instance by exclusing hidden workflows. These hidden workflows list send to repo to ignore them.

You can see the hidden workflow details in share-config.xml file.

I added inline comments in the below funtion.

```
function getWorkflowDefinitions()
{ 
   // Get the hidden workflow list from Share-config or share-config-custom.xml
   var hiddenWorkflowNames = getHiddenWorkflowNames(),
      connector = remote.connect("alfresco"), //create connection to Alfresco repository
      //Get request to repo and telling repo ignore some of the workflows also
      result = connector.get("/api/workflow-definitions?exclude=" + hiddenWorkflowNames.join(","));
   if (result.status == 200)
   {
      var workflows = JSON.parse(result).data;
      //Sort the workflows based on their title
      workflows.sort(sortByTitle);
      return workflows;
   }
 //If there are not workflows, just return empty list to the client.
   return [];
}



<!-- A list of workflow definitions that are NOT displayed in Share -->
      <hidden-workflows>
         <!-- Hide all WCM related workflows -->
         <workflow name="jbpm$wcmwf:*"/>
         <workflow name="jbpm$wf:articleapproval"/>
         <!-- Hide publishing workflows -->
         <workflow name="activiti$publishWebContent"/>
         <workflow name="jbpm$publishWebContent"/>
         <!-- Hide invitation workflows -->
         <workflow name="jbpm$inwf:invitation-nominated"/>
         <workflow name="jbpm$imwf:invitation-moderated"/>
         <workflow name="activiti$activitiInvitationModerated"/>
         <workflow name="activiti$activitiInvitationNominated"/>
      </hidden-workflows>
```

Please let me know, still if you need any help on this.